# Video file split with VLC from the command line gives garbage duration times for split files

Tags: bash, video, command-line, osx-lion, vlc

I have a late 2011 MBP, running Mac OS X 10.7.5, 2.3 GHz Intel Core i5, with 16GB 1600 MHz DDR3.

I wrote the script below to cut up video files in vlc (tested with VLC 1.1.3 and 2.2.1). The script works, however the output files have "dud" durations of 384592 hours

```
#!/bin/bash
filename=test.mkv
duration=`ffprobe -show_format $filename | sed -n '/duration/s/.*=//p'`
duration=${duration/.*}
interval=120
start=0
n=$start
stop=$interval
while [ $duration -ge 0 ]; do
    /Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/VLC -Idummy $filename --start-time $start --stop-time $stop --sout=#file{dst=$n-out-$filename} vlc://quit
    let start=stop
    let stop=stop+interval
    let duration=duration-interval
    echo "Number of seconds left to process: $duration"
    let n=n+1
done
```

### Can anybody share any insight as to why VLC is behaving this way or is it my script?

---

## Update

The issue has something to do with the way VLC handles mkv files.  When I split an mp4 file vs an mkv file the issue went away.  Would still be good to know what is going on with the mkv.

### .MKV split

with the issue, the files are ~2 min in duration NOT 384,592 hours
[image]

### .MP4 split

without the issue, the files lengths are displayed correctly for mp4 files
[image]

Comment: Do not use VLC to split MKV (it's a stream controlling software), you should better use `mkvtoolnix/mkvmerge`   http://fosshub.com/MKVToolNix.html , it's in English too :-)

Comment: Thanks, so there is nothing "wrong" with the script, just standard VLC behavour.

Comment: Look into having the MKV 'repaired' or re-indexed. This type of problem is almost always related to the index, and is fixed/remedied by rebuilding it. You can probably do it with VLC, or you can do it with mplayer, avidemux etc...

Comment: Did you try to echo the duration before going in your while loop?

Comment: @Samoth yes I did ffprobe gives the correct duration before the cutting process. So the entire file is fine, but after cutting ffprobe gives the same readings as vlc.